# No response of SOAP connection with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to establish a SOAP connection between a client and a server.

First in the Client, I send through a .php file information with soap so I can see the request and response:

```
&client = new SOAPclient("http://.../service.wsdl",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,'trace'=>1);
```

After this I call the function `&client->handle_request(&request)`

So far everithing works fine.

I call the server from the wsdl file `http://..../index.php?soap=on`

```
if (soap == on)
{
    include server.inc
    &soapserver = new Juan_soap_server
    &soapserver->handle_request($request)
}
```

in the server.inc I have defined the class `Juan_soap_server` and the function `handle_request`.

My problem is that the programm executes the function `handle_request`, does all their task but after that I get no response in my client.

I have run a simple client server test in the server and it works properly so is not a problem with the soap installation.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Well, (besides a slew of parse errors, I assume this is 'pseudo-code'): you don't actualy _do_ anything with the return. What do you think it should show and why?

Comment: Yes sorry but its Pseudo-code.

I call the function handle_request($request) the $request variable is written in the client and transmitted through SOAP to the server.

The server edit $request, and then I return $request in handle_request() function of the server.

So the server.inc is something like that

class Juan_soap_server{
public function handle_request($request){

return &request}
}

$server = new SOAPServer(NULL, array('uri'=>"urn:service"));
$server->setClass('Juan_soap_server');
$server->handle();

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, when this happened to me in the past, was that the object i was returning didn't math the structure of the type or complextype defined in the web service definition (wsdl) file.

I would recommend you to change the return type to string and just return a simple string from the server side. If this work, then younare sure that is something with the data structure that you are returning.